# Sending File over Socket - termination condition

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I am sending a file over a socket in Java.

This works pretty well if I close the socket connection after I sent the file, so that the read method returns -1.
But I don't want to close the socket, so I need a termination condition.
I tried to use inputStream.available, but its not returning the exact number of bytes.

```
int number;
while((number = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fileStream.write(buffer, 0, number);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

A standard pattern is to send the length first as say an `int` or `long`. e.g. DataInput/OutputStream can help you do this.

When you have read this amount of data, you have finished, but the connection is still open and can continue to be used.

Comment: Oh, thats a nice idea :D I will try it